Is there a word or phrase for when people share a way of thinking?
I’m looking for a word of phrase that describes when two people have not only similar perspectives, but come to those perspectives the same ways. Where their value system and thought processes are so aligned that they inherently understand each others intent because they have the same way of thinking to reach a given conclusion.
For example

Even when the two of them disagree, its only in semantics, at their core they (fill in here for have same thought process)


Maybe they are soulmates.

Metaphoric on the same wavelength is a bit more "modern" than cut from the same cloth.

To be cut from the same cloth is an idiom describing a high degree of similarity between items. It carries a connotation of intrinsic similarity that's in the very "fabric" of the items being compared. If two people are cut from the same cloth, they are similar in many ways, typically referring to their behavior or way of thinking, rather than superficial or transient similarities. It may not indicate total agreement on all subjects, but suggests a fundamental similarity that cuts across multiple areas. There is also some connotation about the similarity of the origin of the two individuals, that perhaps they were raised in similar circumstances or socioeconomic class, or are similar ages, or have some other similarity in their background (the "cloth" from which they are "cut").
To be of the same mind as someone is another way to describe agreement in ways of thinking. It directly indicates that two people think about something the same way. It may be used in a more limited context, indicating agreement about a particular subject, rather than a more overarching similarity in terms of background.


Even when the two of them disagree, it is only in semantics; at their core they ...

see eye to eye
are birds of a feather
are on the same page
are on the same track
march to the beat of the same drum

see eye to eye does not have it. When the two of them disagree, they do not see eye to eye.


but come to those perspectives the same ways

This suggests to me that they are products of the same environment.
